# Snowflake ACCOUNT_USAGE Views - TABLES (ROW_COUNT, BYTES) are not updated within LATENCY period

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-metadata, snowflake-schema

I discovered while gathering metadata stom SNOWFLAKE - "ACCOUNT USAGE VIEWS" that the values in TABLES(ROW_COUNT, BYTES) are not being updated. I expect that there is some LATENCY period delay, but for most objects I have "0". I have to clearly state that those tables are not new. They are there for months.

While comparing with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES I see the up to date figures.
Other (also ACCOUNT_USAGE) view TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS show at least information about size. And its calculated there.

This is my account_usage select:

[image: img1]

```
use schema snowflake.account_usage;
Select table_id, table_catalog, table_schema,table_name, ROW_COUNT , bytes From tables where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND DELETED IS NULL AND table_owner IS NOT NULL
```

and the information_schema select is:

[image]

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema,table_name, ROW_COUNT , bytes From CS_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

[Account Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZNZT.png)
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abkxf.png)

@snowflake Please could you help,
I believe its an error, and it would be benefiacial for all if Snowflake fix the problem.
Or would be someone be able to explain why there is discrepancy?
I dont have 0 for all tables(account_usage), but in most tables.

Best regards,
Petr

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly recommend you document this like you have here and open a Snowflake Support Request.

Here is the link that explains how to do this:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge?_ga=2.44556966.304033970.1592222636-1653238650.1560273432&_gac=1.3262980.1591987547.EAIaIQobChMI9bPQ2_f86QIVAeiGCh3tLQFbEAAYASAAEgIMZ_D_BwE

I hope this helps...Rich

Comment: Thank you Rich for suggestion, I am now trying to get access to submit ticket. For some reason, my community account does not have submit ticket active. But I contacted our snowflake account manager.